# How do I NOT install the apps that Google Play Store offers for review?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, 9.0-pie, nokia-3

I have a new Nokia 3.1. It immediately wanted to download updates, which it did successfully. Now I have a notification that I can't get rid of to "Complete setup by installing apps". When I touch it, I get this:

[image: screenshot of an Android process requesting to download more apps over Wi-Fi]

I can't seem to deselect these. How do I NOT download them, and not be bothered by the offer any more?

Answer (score 1):

Solution found.
Hold on the notification and turn off notifications from play store.

Answer (score 1):

You can make that annoying notification go away by disabling the Android Setup app

1. Got to Settings/Apps and notifications
2. Tap "All apps"
3. tap ... in the top right corner and select "Show system"
4. Search "Android setup" and disable the app, the notification disappears right away, including the one in the settings menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It happened in my Samsung A30s - Android 9.0.

I installed the recommended apps, the notification of `Complete setup by installing apps` gone, and I uninstalled them again.
I seems there is no easy way to get rid of that notification.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch over to mobile data and reboot your phone. Maybe this will hold off the auto-download from wifi.

You can also stop your updates by disabling auto-update in "Updates" section of "My apps and games".